# Is "flyjin" a Japanese word, and if so, does it have an antonym?

Tags: word-requests

Is "flyjin" a Japanese word?

If so, does it have an antonym?

And what is the correct way to write it in Japanese? Is it フライジン or フライ人{じん}?

For those who might be unfamiliar with the term, "[flyjin](https://hoofin.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/a-comment-from-the-coiner-of-the-term-flyjin/)" is a word derived from "gaijin" to describe foreigners who "flew away" from Japan after the earthquke, tsunami, and nuclear incident on March 11, 2011.

Comment: When I searched for `"フライジン"` or `"フライ人"` on Google, most of the results in Japanese had to explain what it meant, and a lot of them were either translations of foreign news articles or people asking "what's a flyjin", so I'm guessing it is used more in English than Japanese. I was going to coin a new term of "stayjin", but it [looks like somebody's already done that...](http://japanory.typepad.co.uk/japanory/2011/04/gaijin-flyjin-stayjin-and-tryjin.html)

Comment: I agree with cypher: although “flyjin” is a word in English based on a loanword “gaijin” from Japanese, I do not think that most Japanese-speaking people consider フライジン as a Japanese word at all.  (Personally, I did not know the word “flyjin” or フライジン.)  So I do not think that this question is a question about the Japanese language.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I also don't know the English word "flyjin", but Andrew did not suggest a (possibly imaginary) word "フライジン". That is what cypher brought into. I don't think the question is particularly not about Japanese. It is asking for an antonym in Japanese for the English word "flyjin" (which I don't know what it is). However, it might be too narrow a question for just asking for a translation of a word.

Comment: It may be possible to explain with something like `東{ひがし}日本{にほん}大震災{だいしんさい}後{ご}日本{にほん}に住{す}み続{つづ}けることにした定住者{ていじゅうしゃ}` "long-term residents who decided to remain in Japan post the Great East Japan Earthquake" (that's probably bad Japanese though)

Comment: @sawa: I just assumed that Andrew assumed that “flyjin” is a Japanese word, because otherwise I would not see any connection between this post and the Japanese language.  Asking for an antonym for some English word in Japanese is, well, beyond my imagination.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I agree. It is unnatural. Andrew should have presented the English antonym for "flyjin", and simply ask what the Japanese translation for it is.

Comment: @Andrew What is a flyjin, and can you give the antonym for it in English? It seems more natural to present an antonym and ask for the Japanese counterpart rather than asking for the counterpart of an antonym for that word.

Comment: @sawa 1) I'll add what a flyjin is to my question - I assumed everyone knew what it meant. 2) I'm not aware of any commonly-accepted English-language antonyms of flyjin.

Comment: Much like 3.11, "Flyjin" is overwhelmingly a word coined and used by non-Japanese, when speaking English. Therefore I fail to see the point of the question on JLU.

Comment: @Dave: The word flyjin, is undeniably sourced out of the Japanese language, and as such is easily mistaken for a Japanese word. So asking about it so that learners coming to this site can discover that it is not a Japanese word seems worthwhile to me. Otherwise, we're saying that no one can ask if a word is Japanese if the answer is ever "no" - which they can't know until they ask, thus that wouldn't be a very rational standard. I would agree the way Andrew asked might not have been ideal, but that it was asked at all seems fair.

Comment: @DaveMG as per my comment to your answer: we essentially agree... except I do not think the question as it stands (with only a very late and minor interrogation on the reason to be for the entire question) is well formulated.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I have no idea why you tagged it as wasei-eigo.

Comment: @Dave, Andrew: I attempted a large edit of the question in hopes of making it uncontroversial for this site. If I have overstepped my bounds, I apologize. I do think it's a valid topic, so my intention was only to try and shed it of controversial tangents.

Comment: @DaveMG I regard your edits as being in good faith.

Comment: I also thought the situation of a word made from a language but not being a part of that language was interesting, so I asked about it on the Linguistics SE site: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/what-is-it-called-when-a-word-is-constructed-out-of-a-language-but-is-not-a-par

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that the word is *constructed out of* the Japanese language, it would be an understandable mistake to think the word was Japanese.

However, "flyjin" is **not** a Japanese word.

The word "flyjin" was coined within the English speaking foreign community in Japan, where the issue of people leaving Japan after the earthquake was a topic of much discussion.

Japanese people, for the most part, are unaware, and unconcerned, about the issues that gave rise to the term. Thus the term "flyjin" is almost entirely unknown to Japanese people.

Following from that, there is no widely accepted "correct" way to write it in Japanese. Nor is there an accepted Japanese equivalent term. If you are speaking to a Japanese person about "flyjin", you will have to explain the concept however you see fit.

For antonyms, they also exist only within the subculture of English speaking foreigners in Japan, and would not be considered "Japanese" words. Still, there are two contenders. One is "stayjin", the meaning and origins of which are self evident.

Another is a term coined by a friend of mine: "fryjin". It refers to "fry", as in those who stayed after the earthquake were "fried" by the radiation from the Fukushima nuclear power plants.

The best part about it is that in katakana, it's the same as "flyjin": フライジン. So Japanese can't tell the difference between the words, just as they don't really differentiate between foreigners who stayed and those who didn't. I like the metacontextual implications.

Comment: +1 for the use of a play on words in one language that would not really be understood in that language.

Comment: The Japanese Wikipedia has an article on [Engrish](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish). Apparently the Japanese word for Engrish is - Engrish! (Makes sense, in that the Japanese word for English is eigo).

Comment: "Is Flyjin a Japanese word?" is about the only way I could see this belonging on JLU... But then again, perhaps my general annoyance with the topic that this question (very unsubtly) tries to broach is informing my opinion here.

Comment: @Dave: I think you're basically right, but Andrew does essentially ask that in the last line of his question: "is it not used much within Japanese as opposed to English?". I also agree that the potential for delving into the implications of the word, as opposed to just its definitions (and antonyms), carries risks, but no worse risk than "why is gaikokujin more politically correct than gaijin", which was also asked and answered here.

Comment: Is nihon saru gaikokujin (日本 去る 外国人) the most common Japanese phrase for the equivalent of the (English) word flyjin?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: I think you might be missing an important point: The Japanese for the most part do not know, *or care*, about the topic of "flyjin". Thus there is no common Japanese phrase or word for this. So if you find yourself explaining it to a Japanese person, you can explain it however you like.